# npm start command with webpack on Windows 10 fails

Tags: npm, webpack, windows-10, webpack-dev-server, npm-start

I am currently using node to build a website. I have run the webpack dev server fine in ubuntu but in windows i cant seem to get the `npm start` command to work
I am able to `npm run build-sw` on both platforms without error but just not able to run.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! site@1.0.0 start: `npm run build-sw && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --no-info --watch-poll`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the site@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get the project running using YARN.
It needed no configuration change.

I had to install Visual C++ but after that
`yarn` and `yarn run start` did the trick.

So on ubuntu I use npm but on windows i use yarn. Works now